# Call to undefined function db_query() in cs cart

Tags: cs-cart

i am working now cs cart framework.i am write now insert query ,Here is my code there.

```
if($_REQUEST['finance'] !=''){
$finance=$_REQUEST['finance'];

 $data = array();
$data = $finance;
$feature_id = db_query('INSERT INTO ?:bootsgrid_pay4later_finance ?e', 
$data);
echo "success";
exit;
}
```

but i got e response

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function db_query() in
```

How can i fix this issue.please help me.

Comment: anybody here please reply me.

Comment: can you please let me know were you add this code ? and for that to work also $_REQUEST['finance'] is required to be an array